# Custom error in web.config not working for 404

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I am trying to set up custom error for my website, which works fine on my local machine but it fails on the server. Below is my code.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors  mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Pages/Error.aspx">       
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Pages/PageNotFound.aspx"/>      
    </customErrors>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough"defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="~/Pages/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>

</system.webServer>
```

I am using IIS 8 on my local server and IIS 7 on the live server. Should I change this code in any way to make it work?

Also, when I try to access a page, eg: xyz.aspx, it does'nt show anything except for a white browser window.

Comment: it fails means you have an error or ? at what level did you add this config root web, web site ?

Comment: no I don't get any error..it give me just the white blank screen...and the config file is in web root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have more then one web config Or Check your web config file is inside your project correctly.

Comment: no I have onyy 1 web.config..and the config file is also..properly placed inside the project...as the website is working fine..

Comment: then where your web config file is placed.? inside any folder or Project?

Comment: Are u using MVC Structure?

Comment: Try this if u are using MVC. <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/site/wwwroot/404.html" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

Comment: Remote only option will show error in local, it hide the error message for remote user only. try for the config file it is for local only and change the version and target framework according to your .Net Version.